# phonegap->find location of the phone without use of GPS(can use internet)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, cordova

I am developing an app using phonegap. Currently I am using GPS phonegap api's to find user location. But using GPS all the time reduces battery performance(My app run's in background to get location of the user) so I want to get the user location using internet. Is there any way to do this.

Thnk u very much in advance.
PSP

Comment: what you tried? post some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the code that the PhoneGap's API uses is the W3C Geolocation API. It will use the best option available to it to find the user's location.

So if GPS is on, it will use that. If not it will use the 3G/H/whatever connection, if it's connected to WiFi it will try and use that.

So basically it will automatically use what it can so you don't need to do anything different.

Answer (score 0):

Well since a smartphone or tablet is able to get on the internet is must have an IP address. And you can trace an IP address for the location of where it is comming from. So you might be able to do something with that. But I think that doing that is way to difficult, so I should say that using the GPS is the only possible way. Besides that it is the easiest way.

Comment: even i found using GPS is the easiest way but that eats off battery